# AzureDevOps - DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 does not download artifact if the very previous run didnt produce artifact

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

We are using Azure Pipelines (YAML not classic) for both build & releases. The stages are as follows:

1. Build
2. Deploy_DEV
3. Deploy_UAT
4. Deploy_PERF
5. Deploy_PROD

The YAML is parameterised that user can select what stages to run. For example:

1. Build & Deploy DEV, or
2. Build + Deploy DEV + Deploy UAT.

Now problem arises in scenarios like below:

1. Build + Deploy DEV. >> Outcome: Works
2. Deploy SIT (DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 with `runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'`) >> Outcome: works because last build Id produced artifact and deployment was successful
3. Deploy UAT (DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 with `runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'`) >> Outcome fails, because the very last deploy job to SIT didnt produce any artifact.

I dont know if its a bug or shortcoming of this pipeline task, but would expect the `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` tasks refer to the very last build Id of the branch **that produced the artifact**. It seem from the logs that `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` task simply tries to download artifact from very previous pipeline run which may not have produced any artifact.

Its very normal during any project to run 1 build & and then deploy that build over time to various environment (promoting artifact). So pipeline stages per run would look like:

1. Build artifact 1 on a commit
2. Deploy artifact 1 to Env x
3. Deploy artifact 2 to Env y
4. Deploy artifact 3 to Env z ... etc.

Can someone advise if this is a shortcoming of the task or am I doing something wrong?

Below is my task configuration:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: Download LATEST artifact
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '$(System.TeamProjectId)'
    definition: '$(System.DefinitionId)'
    runVersion: 'latestFromBranch'
    branchName: '$(Build.SourceBranch)'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

Answer (score 1):

"DownloadPipelineArtifact" task with 'specific' buildType checks the last successful build in the pipeline, if there is no artifact produced in the last successful build, you would get "Artifact art was not found for build xxx". This is how "DownloadPipelineArtifact" task works.

To solve your issue, there are two ways:

1. For every pipeline run, you run two stages (Build + Deployment), then set 'current' buildType for "DownloadPipelineArtifact" task. In this way, you could always get the latest artifact, and I recommend this way.
2. Add "PublishPipelineArtifact" task in each Deployment stage, so that there always have artifact in the pipeline run.

   ```
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          buildType: 'specific'
          project: '94eb5b0e-78fd-4ec0-a3c5-62d5becb6c0f'
          definition: '119'
          buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
          artifactName: 'A.A'
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/A.A'
          artifact: 'A.A'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. 

For #1 - There are cases where we just want to deploy latest build. Ie. we build once and deploy multiple times, so there is 1 stage not 2 in that pipeline run. 

This would save time as builds can take time and either way doing build every time for sake of deploying is redundant.

For #2 - I have tried and it seem an artifact an only be published once. 

Error:
`x-my-aritfaact-20210419.4 already exists for build 7348`

Comment: How did you publish? You may check my updated reply.

Comment: Have you checked my updated reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code with **publishLocation: 'Pipeline'** and still same error:

`##[error]Artifact x-my-artifact-20210421.1 already exists for build 7633.`

I am basically trying to implement option 2 you provided above where we republish same pipeline artifact for reuse across other subsequent pipeline runs.

Comment: My code for PublishPipelineArtifact task:

`- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    artifactName: $(Build.DefinitionName)-$(Build.BuildNumber)
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'`

Comment: You could try my example: in each Deployment stage, add "DownloadPipelineArtifact" task and "PublishPipelineArtifact" task.

Comment: Hi, I did add the "DownloadPipelineArtifact " task before the "PublishPipelineArtifact" task. Still no luck. 

I have shared the deployment pipeline file here (condensed version):

https://gist.github.com/aimtiaz11/bc7b72cc8081777703fb1b1b7c24dd70